# Ionic 4 getting data from database without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, ionic4

I have a Ionic 4 Mobile App,PHP Web Application and I have a phpmysql database, when I inserted a data using my Web Application I want to be view on my Mobile App without refreshing, Im currently using HttpRequest.

I have heard of set Interval but I have heard it will be complicated in the long run.

Comment: With the help of observable, you can do that. Please provide us some code from what you have done, so that we can help you in more details.

Comment: btw using Firebase you get this functionality included, without having to write it. Instead of you investing time in building the product, you have to invest money to use their resources. Depends what type of project you're working on but it could be worth looking into.

Comment: Im really sorry, I haven't written code for this problem but ill start doing so, there is been a suggestion that socket.io well benefit me well.

My Client need my project to be offline so firebase is not an option for me, but i really appreciate the info I'll may use it on the near future dear Sir.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a web socket connection. A web socket is basically a steady connection that listen to event from one to the other. Ex, you add a new entry in your database, you then notify every socket connected so they can retrieve the new information.

There are many libraries available to do socket. I have not tried all of them but i tried [socket.io](https://socket.io/) and it works well. It is Javascript only though. For PHP, you can look into [ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ill try it now really appreciate the info